# open-im-server's mongo don't conected

Tags: mongodb

Starting Mongo failed, connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.;

I have try to connected. And expect to

Comment: How do you connect? "SCRAM-SHA-1" is an old mechanism which is not used anymore. Perhaps you try to enforce it in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the MongoDB container(`docker exec -it mongo bash`);
2. Execute `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh`;
3. Change the username and password in config/config.yaml

```yaml
mongo:
    uri: ''
    username: openIM
    password: openIM123456
```

Comment: Remember to first perform a 'git pull' to update the 'mongo-init.sh' script